# How limiting background jobs works?

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, batch-processing, background-process

while looking on how to parallelize bash tasks, I've stumbles over a code like this:

```
for item in "${items[@]}"
do
  ((i=i%THREADS)); ((i++==0)) && wait
  process_item $item &
done
```

Where `process_item` is some king of function/program that works with item and the `THREADS` var contain the maximum number of background processes that can run simultaneously.

Can someone explain to me how this works? I understand that `i=i%THREADS` ensures that `i` is between `0` and `THREADS-1`, and that `i++==0` increments `i` and checks whether it is `0`. But is `wait` bound to all sub processes? Or how does it know that is has to wait until the previous batch stopped processing?

Answer (score 1):

It's an obfuscated way of writing

```
for item in "${items[@]}"
do
    # Every THREADSth job, stop and wait for everything
    # to complete.
    if (( i % THREADS == 0 )); then
        wait
    fi
    ((i++))
    process_item $item &
done
```

It also doesn't actually work terribly well. It doesn't ensure that there are always `$THREADS` jobs running, only that no more than `$THREADS` jobs are running at once.

Answer (score 0):

`i++==0` checks and increments, not the opposite. `wait` waits for all currently active child processes. So, each iteration (but the first, thanks to the `((i++==0))`) first waits for the process launched by the previous iteration and launches a new process.